# Why can't get superclass's property by getter [typescript]

Tags: typescript

```
class A
{
    protected _value:number;
    get value()
    {
        return this._value;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    set value(v:number)
    {
        this._value = v;
    }
}

var b = new B();
b.value = 2;
console.log(b.value);//undefined
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20_value%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09get%20value()%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this._value%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09set%20value(v%3Anumber)%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09this._value%20%3D%20v%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0Ab.value%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.value)%3B)

can't get value if subclass just define setter only.

I guess when Object.defineProperty "value" to B.prototype, override the "value" getter setter on A.prototype.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a long discussion about [this accessors' restriction in this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338).

For the expected behavior either leave both getter and setter in the super class:

```
class A
{
    protected _value:number;

    get value():number
    {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(v:number)
    {
        this._value = v;
    }
}

class B extends A
{

}
```

or alternatively override both on the subclass:

```
class A
{
    protected _value:number;
    get value():number
    {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(v:number)
    {
        this._value = v;
    }
}

class B extends A
{

    get value():number
    {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(v:number)
    {
        this._value = v;
    }

}
```

If you don't use **accessors** but use normal methods instead the bahaviour is as expected:

```
class A
{
    protected _value:number;
    getvalue():number
    {
        return this._value;
    }

}

class B extends A
{

    setvalue(v:number)
    {
        this._value = v;
    }

}

const b:B = new B();
b.setvalue(2);
console.log(b.getvalue());
```

Comment: thank you for answer. in other language, if subclass have not some function, superclass function will be call. but typescript not.i just confuse this.